# How to use jquery Ajax data action

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to figure out what and how to use the data parameter in a $.Ajax call. The problem is that I am unsure as to what the 'action' part in the data call is supposed to do. Is it an action in a controller? If yes, how do I reference it correctly?

```
var data = {
    action: 'get-all-users',
    data: JSON.parse($('form.post-list input').val())
};

$.ajax({
    url: '/Users/index',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    success: function (response) {
         * code *
    }
});
```

What should 'get-all-users' result to? A Get function in a controller or what?

I am using ASP.NET MVC Core 2.0.

Comment: Hi just think **isn't possible to pass globally any variables to the method Ajax success**, cos is strictly private, only the server can send data from this method.

Comment: I am confused by the name 'action' in the data attribute. Could you explain what it is?

Comment: the `data.action` is an `attribute action of the object data` is a value that you known cos we haven't any reference of this value in your code `get-all-users`. is the parameter you send in the ajax request as POST.

Comment: Okay. Should this reference be in my HTML code or in my C#/Controller code?

Comment: Yes it should be for example : form.post-list input here this meaning you got a `<form action='get-all-user' class="post-list" ...> <input .../>` like this i guess for the action: 'get-all-users', is confused me because **action** is the `<form action="URL" ..>` and in your case i dunno what is it.

Comment: May be you got a method c# named get-all-users and this function catch POST from the ajax request...

Comment: We pass data to controller method (which is index in your case inside Users controller) using data parameter in ajax call. Data parameter in ajax call consist of key-value pairs. Name of keys must match exactly with the input parameters of controller method. You can also set dataType: "json" in ajax call. Do you have input parameter called action in your controller method 'index'?

Answer (score 1):

The property 'action' of the object 'data' is not related to controller (and it is not an action of controller).
The data parameter in $.ajax call contains data to be passed to server. So here you are gonna send the next object to the server:

```
var data = {
  action: 'get-all-users',
  data: JSON.parse($('form.post-list input').val())
};
```

And in order to receive and parse this object on the server side you should have appropriate C# class to provide ModelBinder with a correct data.

One more. In your example Index is an action in Users controller call will be made to. You can see it in 'url' parameter of $.ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Users/Index',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    success: function (response) {
        * code *
    }
});
```