# Find definition of the 'action' inside 'data' object in jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm a back-end dev that inherited code that looks like this

```
            xhr =  jQuery.ajax({

                        type: 'POST',
                        url: ajax_url,  // ERROR!!
                        dataType: "json",
                        data:  {
                                    action: 'properties', <---------------------------------
                                    data: url_vars,
                                    url: document.URL
                                },
```

[image]

I know that the action called **properties** has to be defined somewhere, but I'm not sure how to find it.

I read multiple threads on SO, but this is not a form action, so I'm not sure how one would go about finding it. If an experienced front-end dev saw this name, what would they look for specifically inside the code?

Apologies for the newbie question, but this is a bit confusing.

[Closest answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46869035/how-to-use-jquery-ajax-data-action) I found is *the data.action is an attribute action of the object data is a value that you known cos we haven't any reference*, unfortunately I'm not even sure where to look for *any reference* apart from analyzing 1000+ times the word 'properties' is mentioned in the framework's code.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"I know that the action called properties has to be defined somewhere, but I'm not sure how to find it."* I'm not sure what you mean by "defined somewhere." That code, in the question, **is** defining it. It's defininga  property called `action` whose value is the literal string `"properties"`. It's not referring to anything anywhere else (in relation to `action`).

Comment: thank you, I thought it was referring to a specific action that does something to define 'data'.  I assumed that because console.log(data.action) returns undefined and data has other properties like 'html' which I'm not seeing. Guess I have to figure out where else it gets the properties like 'html' from.

Comment: The `data` in the question only exists as a property in an anonymous object being provided to `jQuery.ajax`. I don't see how you *could* `console.log` it, which suggests that wherever you're doing `console.log(data)`, it's something else entirely that's getting output. Hope that helps!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you! I need to brush up on JS, I'm completely lost at this point..